# Por que o atributo gravity do objeto LinearLayout.LayoutParams não funciona como o método setGravity() da View?

Tags: android, android-layout

**Problema**

Estou trabalhando em uma biblioteca UI para [android](/questions/tagged/android), onde seto os parâmetros de layout (`height`, `width`, `weight` e `gravity`) dinamicamente via código, em um objeto `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` mas o atributo `gravity` não parece ter o mesmo efeito de `setGravity(gravity)` direto na `View`.

> Obs: não seto diretamente a `View` por que na codificação do componente não pretendo ter  acesso a `View` diretamente.

O que faço resumidamente é algo similar a isso:

```java
// width = 0, height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, weight = 1000
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1000);
params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
textView1.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Mas o `textview1` não fica alinhado a direita como deveria.

Já se eu faço o seguinte código dai funciona:

```java
// width = 0, height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, weight = 1000
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1000);
textView1.setLayoutParams(params);
textView1.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
```

**Pergunta?**

- Por que isso acontece?
- `gravity` do objeto `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` e `setGravity` da `View` são atribitos diferentes?
- Qual a diferença entre as duas abordagens?
- Há alguma maneira de obter o mesmo resultado do `setGravity` da `View` no `gravity` do objeto `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`?

> Obs: A `View` que me refiro na questão, no caso é o `TextView`.
>
> Para ficar mais claro, fiz um [exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/CP7jK/1/) em `HTML` do efeito que quero no `layout` do meu `TextView` [android](/questions/tagged/android), através do `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`.

Comment: São atributos diferentes, não? Um me parece ser a gravidade do `LinearLayout`, e o outro a gravidade da `TextView` que fica dentro do `LinearLayout`.

Comment: Na verdade não sei, no inicio acreditei que era a mesma coisa, mais não deve ser, e se assim for, há como setar a gravidade do `TextView` através do `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`?

Comment: O que significa o `textview1` ficar alinhado à direita? É o próprio `TextView` que fica alinhado em relação ao `LinearLayout` que o contém, ou é o texto dentro do `TextView` que fica alinhado à direita?

Comment: @Piovezan, é o texto alinhado a direita, é tipo um grid que estou fazendo, então valores numéricos quero deixar alinhados a direita e strings a esquerda.

Comment: Então creio que não tenha jeito. Porque o `gravity` de `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` se refere ao layout dentro do qual está a `TextView`. Para alinhar o texto contido na `TextView`, você tem que alterar a gravity da própria `TextView` como está fazendo no segundo exemplo. Por que esse segundo exemplo não é viável para você?

Comment: @Piovezan, é que a estrutura atual, não está disponibilizando a `View` para ser setada diretamente, somente o `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`, que é setado a ele. Achei que talvez poderia conseguir o resultado esperado sem ter que setar diretamente a `View`. Mais é possível sim, com alguma mudança de estrutura no componente, se a unica solução for essa e farei.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> - Por que isso acontece?
> - `gravity` do objeto `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` e `setGravity` da `View` são
>     atribitos diferentes?
> - Qual a diferença entre as duas abordagens?

Porque na classe `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` o parâmetro `public int gravity` refere-se a gravidade para a `View` em que o objeto (no seu caso um `TextView`) está associado , diferente da gravidade interna do objeto `TextView` que, no seu segundo exemplo, você utilizou o método `setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT)` que fará com que o texto do `TextView` se alinhe a direita.

> - Há alguma maneira de obter o mesmo resultado do `setGravity` da `View` no `gravity` do objeto `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`?

Não, se essa "`View`" que você se refere seja o `TextView` e o resultado que você necessita seja o alinhamento do texto do `TextView` para esquerda ou direita. Já que o `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` é responsável pela informação por layout filho do esquema associado com `ViewLinearLayout` e não a gravidade interna desses filhos.

Fontes consultadas: [LinearLayout.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html) e [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setGravity%28int%29)

Comment: Sua resposta, parece ser interessante e coerente, andei pesquisando sobre o assunto e parece que `gravity` do `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` é equivalente a `layout_gravity` do [tag:xml], e `setGravity()` seria equivalente ao `gravity` do [tag:xml], fazendo sentido em relação ao que você citou.

Comment: Seria mais preciso dizer que o parâmetro `gravity` de `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` se refere à gravidade do layout dentro do qual se encontra o `TextView`, afetando portanto o posicionamento do `TextView` dentro desse layout e não do que existe dentro do `TextView`.

Answer (score 0):

Mas eu não percebi se queres alinhar o texto a direita dentro da `textview`  ou se queres alinhar a própria `texview` a direita.
Desculpa a resposta mas não tenho reputação para comentar...

Posso te responder a isso dependendo do que queres, se puderes explicar melhor...

**Resposta**

> Não dá para fazer isso através do `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`. Podes é fazer outra coisa, defines 2 tipos de `TextView` no [xml](/questions/tagged/xml), um com texto alinhado a direita outra com o texto alinhado a esquerda, assim quando quiseres usar é só utilizar a que te der mais jeito.

Comment: Alinhar o texto a direita. Fiz um [exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/CP7jK/1/) em [tag:html] do efeito que quero no `layout` do meu `TextView` [tag:android], da maneira que citei na questão, através do `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`

Comment: Não dá para fazer isso através do `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`.
Podes é fazer outra coisa, defines 2 tipos de `TextView` no xml, um com texto alinhado a direita outra com o texto alinhado a esquerda, assim quando quiseres usar é só utilizar a que te der mais jeito.